# Display nested gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a nested GridView with 4 levels,
when i click in "+" to show child GridView i make request to database to download data of current row, every thing work well for me, the only problem i have is in design, all the child GridView display in column of its parent GridView 
this is how it looks:

**Parent GridView**
[image]

**First Child gridView**
[image]

here is my aspx code:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNestedGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:GridView ID="gvCostCenters" runat="server" ....>
           <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShowAccountingPlan" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_AccountingPlansGrid" .../>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAccountingPlan" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="position: relative">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvAccountingPlans" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"....">
                          <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField>                                 
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShowPrograms" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_ProgramsGrid" .../>
                                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrograms" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="position: relative">
                                       <asp:GridView ID="gvPrograms" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ...>
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShowProjects" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_ProjectsGrid" ..../>
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlProjects" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="position: relative">
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="gvProject" runat="server" ....>
                                                                .....
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>                                                                              
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Label" HeaderText="البند " ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                                ....
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>                                                          
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="NumAccountingPlan" HeaderText="الخطة المحاسبية " ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                             ...
                         </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                 </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         ...
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OperatingExpenses" HeaderText="المصروفات التشغيلية" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00);0}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[src*=minus]").each(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
            $(this).next().remove()
        });
    });
</script>
```

My code C#:

```
protected void Show_Hide_AccountingPlansGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass();
            ImageButton imgShowHide = (sender as ImageButton);
            GridViewRow row = (imgShowHide.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
            if (imgShowHide.CommandArgument == "Show")
            {

                _budget = service.GetBudgetById(int.Parse(hfIdBudget.Value));
                row.FindControl("pnlAccountingPlan").Visible = true;
                imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Hide";
                imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "/Content/img/minus.gif";
                string idCostCenter = gvCostCenters.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                GridView gvAccountingPlans = row.FindControl("gvAccountingPlans") as GridView;
                //gvAccountingPlans.ToolTip = costCenterId;
                gvAccountingPlans.DataSource = AccountingPlanData(int.Parse(hfIdUser.Value), int.Parse(hfIdBudget.Value), int.Parse(idCostCenter));
                gvAccountingPlans.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                row.FindControl("pnlAccountingPlan").Visible = false;
                imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Show";
                imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "/Content/img/plus.gif";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { GlobalHelpers.Trace(ex); }
    }
```

I notice that when i delete the UpdatePanel the first child GridView display well, but the others no.
How can i do to display all childs GridView well?

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you please fix the formatting of your aspx mark up.. people are not going to want to scroll all the way to the right just to try and follow what you have and or what you are trying to do..

Comment: what is wrong in this question? is it unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code asp:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNestedGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCostCenters" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ....>
       <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShowAccountingPlan" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_AccountingPlansGrid" ImageUrl="/Content/img/plus.gif" CommandArgument="Show" />                                                    
           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>                                           
            ....
          <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
             <tr visible="false" runat="server" id="trAccountingPlan">
              <td visible="false" runat="server" id="tdAccountingPlan2"></td>
              <td colspan="999" visible="false" runat="server" id="tdAccountingPlan">

              <asp:GridView ID="gvAccountingPlans" runat="server" ....>
               <Columns>
                 .....                                               
               </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>                 
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
```

Code C#:

```
  protected void Show_Hide_AccountingPlansGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ImageButton imgShowHide = (sender as ImageButton);
            GridViewRow row = (imgShowHide.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
            if (imgShowHide.CommandArgument == "Show")
            {
             ...
                imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Hide";
                imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "/Content/img/minus.gif";
                row.FindControl("trAccountingPlan").Visible = true;
                HtmlTableCell tdAccountingPlan = (HtmlTableCell)row.FindControl("tdAccountingPlan");
                HtmlTableCell tdAccountingPlan2 = (HtmlTableCell)row.FindControl("tdAccountingPlan2");
                tdAccountingPlan2.Visible = true;
                tdAccountingPlan.Visible = true;

              ...

            }
            else
            {                    
                imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Show";
                imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "/Content/img/plus.gif";
                row.FindControl("trAccountingPlan").Visible = false;
                HtmlTableCell tdAccountingPlan = (HtmlTableCell)row.FindControl("tdAccountingPlan");
                HtmlTableCell tdAccountingPlan2 = (HtmlTableCell)row.FindControl("tdAccountingPlan2");
                tdAccountingPlan2.Visible = false;
                tdAccountingPlan.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { GlobalHelpers.Trace(ex); }
    }
```